How to select a row group by a column regardless of difference in other columns
I have a table named tbl_user_complete and a query like this:



user_id
bill_id
complete_date




user_1
bill_1
2024-01-14


user_1
bill_2
2024-02-14


user_1
bill_3
2024-05-01


user_2
bill_4
2024-01-03



SELECT user_id
    , bill_id
    , MAX(complete_date) AS complete_date
FROM tbl_user_complete
GROUP BY user_id;

I want to select users having max complete_date and group by user_id only, and expect to result like below:



user_id
bill_id
complete_date




user_1
bill_3
2024-05-01


user_2
bill_4
2024-01-03



But when I run my above query, it said the query needed to be grouped by bill_id also, which returns pretty much a copy of the original table.
How should I fix the query to get the desired result ?

You want to select the row with the maximum complete_date?

If you want to select a whole row which has a max of something, you need to use window functions to partition and order the rows, then select the first in each partition.
with ordered_users as (
  select
    *,
    -- This will be 1 for the bill_id with the highest complete_date.
    row_number() over (
      partition by user_id
      order by complete_date desc
    ) as row_num
  from tbl_user_complete
)
select user_id, bill_id, complete_date
from ordered_users
where row_num = 1;

Demonstration

You could maybe also use Postgres's DISTINCT ON functionality:
SELECT
  DISTINCT ON (1) user_id, bill_id, complete_date
FROM tbl_user_complete
ORDER BY
  user_id, complete_date DESC; -- add ,bill_id if required

This will produce the desired result at least for your sample data. Since I don't know what other data is in your entire table, you need to check whether it works for you.
See this db<>fiddle

Consider self-joining unit level to aggregate level to query data based on aggregate value:
WITH agg AS (
  SELECT user_id
      , MAX(complete_date) AS max_complete_date
  FROM tbl_user_complete
  GROUP BY user_id
)

SELECT uc.user_id
    , uc.bill_id
    , uc.complete_date
FROM tbl_user_complete uc
INNER JOIN agg
   ON uc.user_id = agg.user_id
   AND uc.complete_date = agg.max_complete_date;


This could be more efficient than my window solution, it does not have to sort the table. Tho an index on user_id, complete_date might change that.

@Schwern Can you explain how an index on user_id, complete_date will effect the query? I'm having user_id and complete_date as primary keys.

@BrotherEye In my query, row_number() must sort the rows by user_id and complete_date. An index on (user_id, complete_date) (which you have from your primary key)  is a B-Tree of user_id's and each user_id has a B-Tree of their complete_dates. B-Trees are sorted. So the DB looks up each user_id in the B-Tree, then looks at the last entry in its complete_dates B-Tree; two tree lookups per user_id. This query would also make use of the index for its group by. It would also benefit from an index on complete_date alone.

@BrotherEye Without any indexes, this query does a table scan to find the max for each user_id. This is faster than sorting the table without an index. Neither query will use an index if there are too few rows; indexes add overhead and for small tables scans are faster. Run your queries with explain analyze to see the plan.

SELECT MAX(complete_date) AS complete_date, user_id
FROM tbl_user_complete 
GROUP BY user_id


2024-05-01
This will work but you won't get the bill_id. As soon as you add "bill_id" for selection it must be part of GROUP BY. and as bill ID is unique in your example it splits to each row separate.

I need the bill_id for my subsequent query, so really can't get it off.
